# Typescript - Parameter in Function Expression

Tags: typescript

I have this code - where I'm trying to pass in a string `title`:

```
let GetData: (title: string) => Promise<APIStates<Series[]>>;

if (process.env["REACT_APP_SERVICE_VERSION"] === "development") {
    GetData = useGetDataServiceDummy(title)
}
```

However I keep getting 2 errors and can't figure out the syntax to resolve it:

- `Cannot find name 'title'`
- `Promise<APIStates<Series[]> is not assignable to (title: string) => Promise<APIStates<Series[]>`

Could someone please help me with the syntax to get around this error.

And for reference useGetDataServiceDummy

```
export async function useGetDataServiceDummy(title: string): Promise<APIStates<Series[]>> {
    // do soemthing with `title`
    return { status: "loaded", payload: dummyData };
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You've defined `GetData` as a function, but assigning to it the promise (the function's return value)

Comment: Regarding `title` - in shown part of code it is not defined..

Comment: 1) You're saying `useGetDataServiceDummy` will return a `Promise` and it just returns a regular `Object`. 2) `title` is literally not defined in the snippet you provided 3) You're assigning a return type of a `useGetDataServiceDummy` to `GetData` by calling it `.(title)` and you said it will be a function and not a `Promise` => `: (title: string) => Promise<APIStates<Series[]>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to assign `useGetDataServiceDummy` to `GetData`, however what you're actually doing is calling `useGetDataServiceDummy` and then assigning the return value to `GetData`. Try this instead:

```js
if (process.env["REACT_APP_SERVICE_VERSION"] === "development") {
    GetData = useGetDataServiceDummy
}
```

Comment: Yep - think that was it - I didn't need `useGetDataServiceDummy(title)`

Comment: Although if I'm being fully honest, I don't understand how `title gets passed to `useGetDataServiceDummy`.

Comment: at some later point ` GetData` will get called with a title. Since you've assigned `userGetDataServiceDummy` to `GetData`  that means the dummy function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign `useGetDataServiceDummy(title)` function to `GetData` you should change your definition of `GetData` like this;

```
let GetData: Promise<APIStates<Series[]>>;
```